# Are there any issues with backing up Ubuntu running on an internal SSD drive to an internal HDD?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, backup, ssd

I'm configuring a new Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 computer, and will be using a Samsung 512 GB SSD in my first internal hard drive bay. I've got a couple extra 500 GB HDDs that I don't want to waste, plus extra SSDs are expensive. Can I put one of the extra HDDs in the second hard drive bay and backup Ubuntu to it each night or once a week? Will there be any issues with recovery, performance, etc.? I'm not interested in utilizing the HDD for anything but backup purposes, which I think differentiates it from some related questions that I've seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there shouldn't be any adversary consequences of backing up to an additional hard drive (except increased energy consumption, wear, and decreased performance during backup of course).

Unless you do something fancy (like some proprietary backup solutions), you'll be able to treat your backup drive as a regular storage medium with a common file system. If done right you'll even be able to boot directly from the backup medium.